# Conjugate matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have a matrix $A\in GL(2,\mathbb C)$. What are the conditions on $A$ so that $A$ is conjugated to $-A$? When $A$ is in the center, then this cannot happen. But are there some matrices such that it is true?

Thanks!

Comment: $A = \left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{matrix}\right)$ is conjugated to $-A$ for example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $A$ and $B$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). 
The eigenvalues of $-A$ are exactly $-\lambda$ for all eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$.
Hence a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for $A$ to be conjugate to $-A$ is that for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ also $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the same multiplicity. This condition is also sufficient if $A$ is diagonalizable.
If you want a few examples of such matrices, 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&a\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}, \hspace{10pt}\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&0&c\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix},\hspace{10pt}\begin{pmatrix}1&a&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&b&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
(For any $a,b,c$)
Further notice that if $A$ is conjugate to $-A$ then so is $P^{-1}AP$ for any invertible $P$.

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer!